# Allow background activities when loading bootstrap modal on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I want a bootstrap modal to appear on the bottom left corner of the page on page load and allow it to disappear only when the x button is clicked and not when clicked anywhere on the screen. I have got these working till now but the next issue is that when the bootstrap modal is loaded it prevents any background activity like page scrolling or link clicking or any such thing and adds a background shade with opacity in front of the screen. How can I make the shade disappear and allow accessing the website while the modal is loaded and displayed in the bottom left corner?

Here are my codes.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).on('load',function(){
      $('#myModal').modal('show');
  });
  $('#myModal').modal({
    backdrop: 'static',
    keyboard: false
  });
});
</script>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your not after a modal dialog, but something that looks like one.

You can still render a modal, but don't call `.modal` on in, and then just handle the close events yourself.

eg.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).on('load',function(){
    var m = $('#myModal');
    m.show();
    m.find("button").on("click", 
      function () { m.hide(); });
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="myModal" class="modal show" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```